# NOT hover JQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm building a multilevel (fixed to 3 levels) menu using JQuery. Everything is working fine but what I'd like to do is making all the levels disappear when any of them are being hovered.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$('#categories AND #subcategories AND #tags').live('-NOT-mouseover', function(){
    $('#categories, #subcategories, #tags').remove();
});
```

Also, I don't know how to get an AND operator on a JQuery selector.

Comment: Maybe a pure CSS implementation? I believe that would be more robust...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas. Not supported in all major browsers.

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding your question. You are saying that the menu is visible at the start and then you want it to disappear when you move the mouse into it? Or do you mean you want them to disappear with the mouse leaves?

Comment: @gdoron I believe I could make it work in IE8. (And IE7/6 are pretty much dead, so chances are OP doesn't need to support them.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas. Yahoo and jQuery and a lot more libraries thinks it's important to support them.

Comment: @MarkEirich the comma means OR. And sorry for my poor description, English isn't my native language :P. This is a more accurate description:
1. The menu is hidden.
2. When you press a button, the first menu level is loaded (with remote data, using ajax)
3. When you hover any element of the first level, you'll get a second  level loaded (using ajax).
4. When you hover any element of the second level, you'll get a third  level loaded (using ajax as well).

Then I want those levels to disappear when your mouse leaves all three levels.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by AND - how could an element have more than one ID?

Comment: Each element has one id. But there are 3 different elements there that I need to know are not hovered (any of them). For avoid closing the menu before I get to the third level.

Comment: Please post your HTML, or create a jsFiddle

Comment: I hope I'm doing this right: http://jsfiddle.net/Srvet/

Comment: You can't put PHP in your jsfiddle; also, jsfiddle will need full URLs to all assets. You can load jQuery and jQuery UI using the frameworks menu on the left.

Comment: Ok. thanks. idk if my server's security will allow data to be pulled from your computer. (I'm using jsonp though)
http://jsfiddle.net/Srvet/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13260/discussion-between-mark-eirich-and-multitut)

Comment: You still have PHP in your fiddle, and you still need to put in the full URLs. Also, you can remove the script tags from the HTML

Answer (score 6):

to select it you can do:

```
   $(".commonClass:not(:hover)")
```

or (yes both of them work)

```
$('#categories:not(:hover), #subcategories:not(:hover), #tags:not(:hover)')
```

Although it is really ugly this second one..

If it's the "over out" that you want:

```
$(yourselector).hover(handlerOut);
```

(which means)

```
$(yourselector).hover(function(){ console.log("i've just existed whatever you had in your selector"); });
```

The "AND" you want, I don't think it is supported. You will probably have to do something like this

```
$("#categories, #subcategories, #tags").hover(function(){
   if($('#categories:hover, #subcategories:hover, #tags:hover').length==0){
      doStuff();
   }
});
```

Comment: i know :P but it was for illustration purposes

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use `live`.
2. Give those elements a class
3. `remove` removes the elements from the DOM for good!, just hide them.

**Code:**

```
$('.classForThoseelements').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

Of course you can still use the `id`s:

```
$('#categories, #subcategories, #tags')...
```

But it's not that clean.

Comment: 1. Thanks, I'm using live because I load those elements to the DOM after the document is ready.
2. Gave the elements a class.
3. Thanks for the advice! :)

And that code hides all the elements as soon as my mouse leaves one of them.  I need a way to know that you've leave all of them.

Comment: @Multitut. You can register to the mousemove event and see what element is hovered. note it's a "heavy" operation.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I think I understand the question, here's a stab at the answer:

```
var leaveTimer;
$('#categories, #subcategories, #tags').hover(function() {
    if (leaveTimer) clearTimeout(leaveTimer);
}, function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    leaveTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $this.remove();
    }, 500);
});
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LFdsV/

Although I don't know why you aren't using `.show()` and `.hide()` vs. adding and removing the elements.

Also note that the above will only work if your menu elements are nested.

Comment: that'd close the menu as soon as you leave the first level.

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem if your menu elements are nested. I'm creating a jsFiddle now to test.

Comment: Now waiting for you to post your HTML. Keep in mind that this problem has been solved many times: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/